# Xcode finding multiple lines using regular expression

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, cocoa, replace

I have the following lines in my code at many places. I want to find all of them at once and replace each of such block with new comment. However i am able search single line at a time. But i am not getting how to include new line in my regular expression to search please help.

```
// Block Solver
// We develop a block solver that includes the joint limit.
// when the mass has poor distribution (leading to large torques about..
//
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking about how to find commented lines using your editor? Which one?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Question is about finding in the editor itself, using Xcode,s find and replace.

Answer (score 5):

Search for:

```
^(?://.*\n?)+
```

and replace all with nothing.

This will find all lines that start with `//`.

Comment: yes, you are right Tim. Could you suggest me what should i do if i want to find each such block as shown in my question which contains three commented lines, at once. Thank you.

Comment: It should be matching the entire block at once. Isn't it doing that?

Comment: It is currently matching each line separately. In my case i should search all three lines as in my question at a time, for uniqueness. It aslo helps in replacing such blocks. Each result should be a block containing three commented lines.

Comment: Try `^(?://.*\n){3}` - does this work? I don't own a Mac, so I can't test this myself.

Comment: Tried it. Not working. I also tried by removing '^' and again by pasting the expression three times but no luck. I dont know why but, whenever i try to match something which presides a newline character, it wont work and my be number of occurrence '{}' is also not working.

Comment: Does `\r\n` work instead of `\n` alone? I would have expected only `\n` in a Mac environment, but perhaps you're matching against Windows files?

Comment: Using exp `^(?://.*(\r\n)+)+` getting zero results but `^(?://.*(\r\n)?)+` matches single lines with comments as it says zero or more occurrence of (\r\n). I am in Mac environment.